# How can I add smtp support?

Tags: function, smtp, php

First of all, I'm new here and PHP :).

My question is about Smtp support. My code is doing send recover password. But my hosting need smtp support. I didn't add it. I read a lot post but my knowledge basic.
How can I add smtp support?

```
  function sendRecover($to, $title, $url, $from, $username, $salt) {

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$title.' <'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
$subject = 'Password Recovery - '.$title;
$message = 'A password recover was requested, if you didn\'t make this action please ignore this email. <br /><br />Your Username: <strong>'.$username.'</strong><br />Your Reset Key: <strong>'.$salt.'</strong><br /><br />You can reset your password by accessing the following link: <a href="'.$url.'/index.php?a=recover&r=1" target="_blank">'.$url.'/index.php?a=recover&r=1</a>';

return @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify your actual problem with your code? You mention needing smtp support on your server which you don't have, so is it a code issue or not?

Comment: smtp4dev is a no sweat no pain for adding mail server in your server

Comment: @catchamonkey i must add smtp support like
'smtp_port = 25
username = web@acme.com
password = webpass
sendmail_from = send@acme.com'

But i didnt integrate it in my code. It's not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer.)

The current "official" version of PHPMailer is available through Github:
 https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

For implementation you can refer the links below : 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3855686/PHP-Mailer-Script-Step-by-Step.htm

```
or
```

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp

If you have access to edit the php.ini then you can do something like this:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = ssl://smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
username = info@Mmydomainname.com
password = myemailpassword
sendmail_from = info@mydomainname.com
```

Comment: How can i integrate PHPMailler? :) My php knowledge basic. Thanx for answer @Arvind im using normal hosting i cant modify php.ini

Comment: I saw updated answer thank you. Can i integrate it in my function? because if i modify my function then web site is not working just showing blank white page..So i dont know very good php.

Comment: you have to implement at least one of the approach

Comment: Still i didn't add it. @Arvind Thanks for all the answers

Comment: Welcome .. keep trying to implement in order to learn new things.